# Unable to move from controller to view in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC framework for my project. 
I am unable to get my code running from controller to view.
Sharing the important chunk of code here.....

Inside AdminController.java controller

```
        System.out.println("controller returning");
        return new ModelAndView("dataFrame_","frameData",dataString);
```

Inside `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
     <bean name="/dataFrame.htm"
        class="com.organization.dept.spec.proj.module.controller.DataFrameController" >
         </bean>
     <bean id="dataFrameViewResolver"
        class="com.organization.dept.spec.proj.module.view.DataFrameViewResolver">
        <property name="dataFrameView">
            <bean class="com.organization.dept.spec.proj.module.view.DataFrameView" />
        </property>
        <property name="dataFramePrefix" value="dataFrame_"></property>      
    </bean>
```

inside DataFrameViewResolver.java

```
     public class DataFrameViewResolver extends AbstractCachingViewResolver {

 private String dataFramePrefix;

 private View dataFrameView;

 @Override
 protected View loadView (String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
        View view = null;
           if(viewName.startsWith(this.dataFramePrefix)){
                view = dataFrameView;
           }
            return view;
        }
```

and

```
public String getDataFramePrefix() {
    return dataFramePrefix;
}

public void setDataFramePrefix(String dataFramePrefix) {
    this.dataFramePrefix = dataFramePrefix;
}

public View getDataFrameView() {
    return dataFrameView;
}

public void setDataFrameView(View dataFrameView) {
    this.dataFrameView = dataFrameView;
}


}
```

inside DataFrameView.java ...

```
public class DataFrameView extends AbstractView {

    @Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map map, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("RenderMergeoutputModel");  //line 99
```

I was unable to get the above system.out.println i.e. was unable to execute my code till that line 99.
The localhost log files of tomcat revealed some exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` 
I put the jstl-1.2.jar in lib and this could just get me rid of exception however still was unable get sysout of DataFrameView of line 99.

Comment: I get no exception... neither on the apache catalina console nor in any of it's log file. So I am unable to get where exactly something is going wrong. Hard to debug.

Comment: Any reason why you need create your own ViewResolver by extending AbstractCachingViewResolver?

Comment: @yorkw : Can we use any inbuilt viewResolver? If yes can I use any such inbuilt viewResolver for differt types of data being passed from from controller to view.........